# CSS background will not reset. It is haunted

Tags: css, background

I can not explain this at all, but I've put a theme selector on my site. A javascript dropdown box that changes the CSS the site is using.

Theme 7 is a theme that had an image of lights in the background. I didn't think it worked with the rest of it so I changed it to a different image using cPanel on my hoster, hit save, and it saved and changed like any other file.

I refreshed multiple times to get the changes, and scrolled down to Theme 7 to see how the new image looked.

Same image as before.

I tried a new image. Same thing.

....I deleted the line background-image altogether, and then quit out of the browser and restarted it.

The lights are still there.

What is going on??? I'm using Chrome btw. In Safari the image was just straight black. I think I've stumbled on a cursed picture.

Here's the css

```
body {
    font-family: Calibri, Arial;
    text-align:center; 




    */background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-size: 100%;*/

    }

input {
    padding: 3px; 
    font-size: 22px;
    }

select {
    padding: 4px;
    }




/*-----CLASSES-------*/

More stuff here
```

Comment: `exorcism` - nice tag :)

Comment: Yeah it actually existed 3 times before :)

Comment: I wonder how it resisted the holy water thrown on it during the tag clean up...

Comment: Either you haven't actually made the change to the file/s you think you have, or your browser's cache is stuck, dump it manually and re-start.

Comment: I added the css that is showing lights. Do you see anything specifying a picture? I don't

Comment: Thanks it was the cache, does this happen often??

Comment: css and javascript are seldom dynamic content; most browsers cache these aggressively;  this is especially true of css.  While most browsers will do conditional requests on html or images, they won't even *check* for updated css.  In principle, that's a good thing, it makes the browsing experience more responsive; but it is a big headache for designers.  Some frameworks have a "development mode" that will add the cache smashing `?123412341234` to the media links stuff when on, but not when off.

Comment: @user1159454: Usually CTRL+F5 (in the more popular browsers) will reload without the cache — every now and then you'll have to dump it manually, though... until they make perfect browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably cached the css you were using before in your browser (and possibly the image too?)  That's the only answer that makes much sense.  You can force-clear the browser's cache of the css by changing the call to the file my-styles.css?abcdefghijkl in your html (or wherever it is you are loading up the styles from).... but manually clearing your cache will work too.

Comment: Normally, the current timestamp is appended to the URL, so that each time it's requested the URL is different, and therefore not cached.  `my-styles.css?1336771324978`

Comment: Yes, what Rocket says is correct.  I just made it abcd so it would be easy to test if that was your issue or not.  It's usually the timestamp of the last time the file was updated, not necessarily the timestamp every time someone opens the page.  It's good to cache it, but the cache should be cleared when the file is changed :)

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing `ctrl+r` to clear Chrome's cache.

Comment: @user1159454: Yes, but it'll refresh with an empty cache.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to incorporate a dynamic Cache Control... every time you change the theme with javascript, have it change or reload the cache so your users won't have to continuously clear their own cached files when they change the theme... Depending on what server you are using, you can do this with php and .htaccess or .NET and web.config, im not sure if there is a way to do it with javascript directly..?